# Is it possible to remove a function within a function with an event listener?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm currently doing The Odin Project Webpack Restaurant Project. I'm focusing on `Tab Switching`, I had an idea that maybe with an event listener. I can remove a specific function within another function and replace it. So let's say, |

I have a main container function, inside that main function. I can call other functions to display html content such as `home`, `about`, `menu`, etc...

I click on the `about` link. It will take out the `home()` and replace it with `about()`, which will now display abouts html content to the screen.

OR

should I call all the functions inside that mainContainer but when clicking on a link or tab, it will give it a style of `seen` and the others will be given `hidden`.

This is just me brainstorming on how I'm going to approach the problem. Just want to see if it's possible for the first one. If not, I'll do the second option I thought of.

Comment: You can try React.

Comment: @Shuo I could but the main focus is using webpack at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea that you can think about.

Suppose you have three pages in your menu called `Home` `About` `Contact`. You should conditionally render these pages, based on the which menu option the user clicks. That means that each page should have its own separate function which will render all the necessary elements needed for the page. That function will then be called when the user clicks a certain menu option.

Your header can be static, and not be re-rendered since it is not going to change. I suppose your `Home` page will be rendered first upon loading the site. When a user presses a different menu option, you should also have a `clearPage` function that will delete all elements and prepare the page to render elements from other functions.

That's a high level answer, the implementation is up to you.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I just target the element id, use switch statements. Make a function that clears up the innerHTML of the container and call that specific tab